# Adding MIME type to be used by Visual Studio 2012 Page Inspector (Web Browser)

Tags: json, mime-types, page-inspector

It looks like .JSON files aren't recognizable TEXT/JSON MIME-types in Visual Studio 2012 Page Inspector. How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a similar issue and had to find the config for IIS Express so I could add the mime types. For me, it was located at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` and I was able to add in the correct "mime map" there.